# How to send numbers from C# to Arduino Uno with a usb port?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I want to send integer numbers (between 101 and 1616)from the c# program to the arduino Uno using a usb port.
I know how to use registers of the arduino Uno and wanted to know if there is a interrupt when reviving data over this USB port.
At the moment I am using this but it isn't working.

`if(Serial.available()!=0)
{
input= (unsigned char)Serial.read(); 
}`

And on the C# program I am using this code:

```
 byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyIntx);
                SerialPort.Write(b, 0, 4);
```

How can i send bigger numbers between the c# program and the arduino uno?
And is there a special interrupt for receiving these type of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is send byte by byte. There are complex solutions and there are easy ones
Complex: from https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-multi-digit-integers.html

```
 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

unsigned int integerValue=0;  // Max value is 65535
char incomingByte;

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {   // something came across serial
    integerValue = 0;         // throw away previous integerValue
    while(1) {            // force into a loop until 'n' is received
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      if (incomingByte == '\n') break;   // exit the while(1), we're done receiving
      if (incomingByte == -1) continue;  // if no characters are in the buffer read() returns -1
      integerValue *= 10;  // shift left 1 decimal place
      // convert ASCII to integer, add, and shift left 1 decimal place
      integerValue = ((incomingByte - 48) + integerValue);
    }
    Serial.println(integerValue);   // Do something with the value
  }
}
```

My Version:
Convert Int to Char, Send byte by byte and In Arduino Convert it back to Int.

```
    int x=150;
    string x_char = x.ToString();
for(int i=0;i<x_char.length();i++)
{
//Send Each Character to Arduino  "c_char[i]".
}
//Send a new line or any special character to mark the break. For Instance "\n";
```

IN Arduino:

```
String a;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps

}

void loop() {

while(Serial.available()) {

a= Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); //Read until new line 
x = Serial.parseInt(); //This is your Integer value

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Connect();
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {

                int MyInt = ToInt32(lblMixerCase.Text);
                byte[] b = GetBytes(MyInt);
                serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 1);

                int MyInt2 = ToInt32(txtRPM.Text);
                if (MyInt2<=255)
                {
                    byte[] z = GetBytes(MyInt2);
                    serialPort1.Write(z, 0, 1); //For first 1 byte numbers
                }
                else if (MyInt2<=510)
                {
                    byte[] r = GetBytes(MyInt2);
                    serialPort1.Write(r, 0, 2); for 2 byte numbers
                }
                else if (MyInt2<=765)
                {
                    byte[] a = GetBytes(MyInt2);
                    serialPort1.Write(a, 0, 3); //for 3 byte numbers
                }
                else if (MyInt2<=1020)
                {
                    byte[] q = GetBytes(MyInt2);
                    serialPort1.Write(q, 0, 4); //for 4 byte numbers
                }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.